# Use middleware in graphql-yoga server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, apollo-client, apollo-server

hope you guys can help me.

At the frontend I'm using the apollo-client. I save my access-token in memory and my refresh-token in a http-cookie. If the access-token is exp. I fetch with the next query a new one. I'm using therefor the [apollo-link-token-refresh](https://github.com/newsiberian/apollo-link-token-refresh). And I get back a new valid access-token with the query I requested. I'm using the graphql-yoga server

My problem:
Before I send back the new access-token I need the new access-token in the context for the query I made originally, else I'm using the invalid old token for the query(I send the access-token in the header for each query).

```
import { GraphQLServer } from "graphql-yoga";

const server = new GraphQLServer({
    typeDefs: "./src/schema.graphql",
    resolvers,
    context(request) {
     return { db, pubsub, prisma, request };
    },
    fragmentReplacements
});

server.express.use(
    cors({
        origin: "http://localhost:8080",
        credentials: true
    })
);

server.express.post("/refresh_token", cookieParser(), async (req, res) => {
    //logic for my access-token, before I return the access-token I need it in the context 
    //for the query I make at the same time! 
    return res.send({ ok: true, accesToken: generateToken(user) });
})

server.start({ cors: false }, () => {
    console.log("The server is up!");
});
```

I guess I can solve this problem with a middleware. Thx for any help